# How can I change the default shortcut in Windows for closing programs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I like the close program keyboard shortcut in Mac OS X which is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>. Nice and convenient for hand placement. In Windows however, the equivalent shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, a little awkward.

Is there a way to change the default keyboard shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Alt+F4 closes windows, not programs. You can probably cook something up in AutoHotkey, but since Windows program commands don't always show up in menus, you might lose some commands that are executed using Ctrl/Alt+Q

Comment: Alt+F4 will close a program for me. I just checked the 'Quit' command in Word and it's Alt+F4. Perhaps a registry edit? Not sure where to look though.

Comment: If programs close when their last window is closed, then yes, Alt+F4 closes programs if you use it to close their last open window. But it's not *generally* a "quit program" shortcut. There's no such thing as the Keyboard Shortcuts preferences pane in OS X on Windows. Your only hope is input redirection (like I suggested) or a third-party tool.

Comment: In my Windows, ALT+F4 also closes the whole program, even if it has more than one document/window opened. STRG+F4, however, closes a single document window. This is applicable to most, if not any, programs I use on Windows.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Get [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Open Notepad and paste the following:

```
^q::Send !{F4}
return
```

Save it as an .ahk file, run it and try it out. If it works, stick it in your startup folder and you are good to go. The above code simply maps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

If you want it to be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, then replace the `^` with a `!`

If you can't get AutoHotKey, I've compiled the above script for you and uploaded it here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26194020/CtrlQ.exe

Download and enjoy.

By the way - you do know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> closes a window in any application already, right?

Comment: Ctrl+W is merely a common shortcut that has been adopted by many programs. It is not defined by Windows and doesn't work in all, or even most, applications.

Comment: Share and enjoy.

Comment: I took me a while before I realized you actually have to double click the resulting file. So here's my FYI, don't look in AutoHotKey for a way to run it and just run the file. Totally works btw.

Comment: FIY, `#` represents the Win key. Also in AutoHotKey V2 it would be `#q::Send "!{F4}"` for Win+Q -> Alt+F4.

Answer (score 3):

To change Windows to suit a Mac user, see this article : [Key Remapping in Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20120828051035/http://www.inertreactants.com/?p=183).
It contains an [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that maps many Windows keys to their Mac equivalents.

To build a new keyboard layout, see [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339), which lets you manipulate all keys and their combinations.

As the original article has disappeared from the Web, I copy below the
Autohotkey script:

```
;Autohotkey script
;John Walker, 2010-11-25
;http://www.inertreactants.com
;Feel free to reuse, edit and redistribute
;Key remaps for Apple users using boot camp
;(with an Apple notebook or Keyboard)

;following section remaps alt-delete keys to mimic OSX
;command-delete deletes whole line
#BS::Send {LShift down}{Home}{LShift Up}{Del}

;alt-function-delete deletes next word
!Delete::Send {LShift down}{LCtrl down}{Right}{LShift Up}{Lctrl up}{Del}

;alt-delete deletes previous word
!BS::Send {LShift down}{LCtrl down}{Left}{LShift Up}{Lctrl up}{Del}

;following section mimics command-q and command-w
;behaviour to close windows
;note these had to be disabled below for the
;command to ctrl key remaps
#w::^F4
#q::!F4

;following section remaps alt-arrow and command-arrow
;keys to mimic OSX behaviour
#Up::Send {Lctrl down}{Home}{Lctrl up}
#Down::Send {Lctrl down}{End}{Lctrl up}
#Left::Send {Home}
#Right::Send {End}
!Up::Send {Home}
!Down::Send {End}
!Left::^Left
!Right::^Right

;following section remaps command key to control key
;affects all number and letter keys
;note that some keys, like winkey-l and winkey-d
;need to be remapped a differeny way
;otherwise autohotkey will not take over
#a::^a
#b::^b
#c::^c
#d::^d
#e::^e
;following won't remap using the normal method
#f::Send {LCtrl down}{f}{LCtrl up}
#g::^g
#h::^h
#i::^i
#j::^j
#k::^k
;#l::Send {LCtrl down}{l}{LCtrl up} ;disabled, I like winkey-L
#m::^m
#n::^n
#o::^o
#p::^p
;#q::^q ;disabled --remapped to alt-F4 instead
#r::^r
#s::^s
#t::^t
#u::^u
#v::^v
;#w::^w ;disabled --remapped to ctrl-F4 instead
#x::^x
#y::^y
#z::^z
#1::^1
#2::^2
#3::^3
#4::^4
#5::^5
#6::^6
#7::^7
#8::^8
#9::^9
#0::^0
```

Comment: Two out of three links are dead :(

Comment: @NathanFriend: I have replaced the links with equivalents, which still seem pertinent, and also copied here the Autohotkey script.

Comment: In this context, I'd like to also mention [KbdEdit](http://www.kbdedit.com/) which is one of my favorite utilities.

Answer (score 0):

(am aware this is from 2011, but for those still reading, a better solution now exists)

(For Win10+ users) If you are using a touchscreen laptop/tablet eg Microsoft Surface, I cannot recommend the app '**GestureSign**' enough. It basically does (most of) what AutoHotkey can do with re-mapping keyboard shortcuts, but with the added functionality of touchscreen, pen, trackpad and mouse inputs.

The GUI is also very easy to use, although programmers might prefer more direct control like scripting.

With this in mind, download GestureSign and add a new shortcut re-mapping whichever new key combination you'd like to ALT+F4. Easy to do and works a charm.

(PS. This is not an ad; I have no connection to GestureSign)