# alt f-4 alternatives?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the default shortcut in Windows for closing programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/250435/how-can-i-change-the-default-shortcut-in-windows-for-closing-programs)

Hi all, alt-f4 is pretty hard to press (or pretty slow) so I was wondering does anyone know of any other key combinations to close windows? (I've tried Control A-Z but all doesn't work..)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> is an alternative (English Windows, other languages might use something else instead of <kbd>C</kbd>)

Comment: you should add that `alt-space` opens the window menu and depending on your language `c` either hits the `close` menu entry or something else...

Answer (score 5):

You can always use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for such jobs.

A script like:

```
LWin::Send !{F4}
```

Will close the window with the left Win key.
[Documentation for AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm).

Comment: cool but i don't like these stuff. they aren't scalable at all

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> works in numerous programs... notably Windows Explorer and most web browsers (IE, FireFox, & Chrome).  If you spend a lot of time surfing this will certainly save a lot of reaching for <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.